# How do i find corresponding user using the userid in reviews in firebase rtdb

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch corresponding user data from the path users/ after fetching the reviews to a recyclerview

So I have done the 2nd part that all review data is fetched on the list map and ready to display on RecyclerView.

But before that, I need to fetch Username and Userpicture from path users/ (not all of them but the only ones whose id is present in reviews)

So how do I do this using the Firebase query?

I mean if we have the userid inside the path it will be easy to find it by looking for the key value.

but the problem is I don't have it in users/

the user id is the child key

So the question is how do I search for the child key? instead of searching for a value.

please see the image below for Realtime Database structure:

[image: firebase rtdb]

Comment: To understand better. Do you need to get the UID from `users` and find the projects of that particular user? Is that correct?

Comment: No im Displaying the reviews for each project. But if i fetch all data under the review path i will only get date,review, and uid. But after getting that UID. i need to search for the UID in users path to get User picture and Username of that specific user. To display along with the reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment:

> I'm displaying the reviews for each project. But if I fetch all data under the review path I will only get the date, review, and the UID. But after getting that UID, I need to search for the UID in the `users` collection to get the User picture and username of that specific user. To display along with the reviews.

To solve this you need to create a reference that points to a specific project, then get all reviews, and based on the UID that you get, create another database call to get user data. So please try the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference projectIdRef = db.child("reviews").child("projects").child("ds1619951195");
projectIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> reviewTask) {
        if (reviewTask.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot reviewSnapshot : reviewTask.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String date = reviewSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String review = reviewSnapshot.child("review").getValue(String.class);
                String user = reviewSnapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class);

                DatabaseReference uidRef = db.child("users").child(user);
                uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> userTask) {
                        if (userTask.isSuccessful()) {
                            DataSnapshot userSnapshot = userTask.getResult();
                            String username = userSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                            String picture = userSnapshot.child("picture").getValue(String.class);
                            Log.d("TAG", username + "/" + picture);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```